# Split XML based on Tag values

Tags: xml, perl, tags

Hi I have an XML and I want that to be split into multiple XML's based on a tag value inside it.

Example:-

```
<HEADER>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>ABC</TAG1> 
<TAG2>78011DAC8</TAG2> 
<TAG3>US78011DAC83</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>ABC</TAG1> 
<TAG2>78011DAD6</TAG2> 
<TAG3>US78011DAD66</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>ABC</TAG1> 
<TAG2>B06983611</TAG2> 
<TAG3>GB0009075325</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>ABC</TAG1> 
<TAG2>B06983629</TAG2> 
<TAG3>GB0009081828</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>ABC</TAG1> 
<TAG2>BRS038D62</TAG2> 
<TAG3>FR0010050559</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>ABC</TAG1> 
<TAG2>BRS49ESZ5</TAG2> 
<TAG3>GB00B1Z5HQ14</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>DEF</TAG1> 
<TAG2>B06983637</TAG2> 
<TAG3>GB0008983024</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>DEF</TAG1> 
<TAG2>BRS26Y2R4</TAG2> 
<TAG3>GB00B128DH60</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>DEF</TAG1> 
<TAG2>BRS1JW2X3</TAG2> 
<TAG3>FR0010235176</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>DEF</TAG1> 
<TAG2>BRS1JW2Y1</TAG2> 
<TAG3>GB00B0CNHZ09</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>DEF</TAG1> 
<TAG2>BRS3BP9P2</TAG2> 
<TAG3>GB00B1L6W962</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>DEF</TAG1> 
<TAG2>BRS7FFAV6</TAG2> 
<TAG3>GB00B3D4VD98</TAG3> 
</ROOT> 
<ROOT>
<TAG1>DEF</TAG1> 
<TAG2>B0A07E1X7</TAG2> 
<TAG3>GB0031790826</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>DEF</TAG1> 
<TAG2>BRS1Z0T57</TAG2> 
<TAG3>GB00B0V3WQ75</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>XYZ</TAG1> 
<TAG2>BRS9ZDYJ6</TAG2> 
<TAG3>FR0010899765</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>XYZ</TAG1> 
<TAG2>BRS8ANE14</TAG2> 
<TAG3>DE0001030526</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>XYZ</TAG1> 
<TAG2>BRS22TXL8</TAG2> 
<TAG3>DE0001030500</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>XYZ</TAG1> 
<TAG2>BRS5LHPB7</TAG2> 
<TAG3>GB00B24FFM16</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
<ROOT>
<TAG1>XYZ</TAG1> 
<TAG2>B06983223</TAG2> 
<TAG3>GB0008932666</TAG3> 
</ROOT>
</HEADER>
```

In the above example, i need to check for TAG1 value and if it matches with the next TAG1 value it should not split and if doesn't matches then it should split into a new XML file...

Appreciate your help !!!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a relatively simple way to do this using XML::Twig. The maximum size kept in memory is a whole sub-file, in case that's important (it would be possible to do better, keeping at most 1 `ROOT` in memory).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie qw( open);

use XML::Twig;

my $in_file = $ARGV[0];

my $out_file= "$in_file.p";
my $i="01";
my $current_tag1='';


my $twig=XML::Twig->new(   
    twig_handlers => { 
       ROOT => sub { my( $t, $root)= @_;
                     $current_tag1||= $root->field( 'TAG1');      # initialize current tag if needed

                     if( $root->field( 'TAG1') ne $current_tag1)  # found a break in the value of TAG1 
                       { 
                         $root->cut;                              # get the new root out of the way
                         $t->print_to_file( $out_file. $i++);     # output the part
                         $t->purge;                               # remove the content of the part
                         $root->paste( first_child => $t->root);  # put the new root back in place

                         $current_tag1=  $root->field( 'TAG1'); 
                       }
                   }
    },
    keep_spaces => 1, # to keep line returns
);

$twig->parsefile($in_file);
$twig->print_to_file( $out_file . $i); # output the last part
```

Comment: Thanks mirod .. this script is able to split the files based on TAG1 value, but i wanted to split the XML file based on some record count (say 3) and check for TAG1 value for the immediate record if it matches then dont break even though record count is 3. Instead stop only after it doesn't find the same TAG1 value ... in our example TAG1 value is ABC for first 5 records so first part1 xml file should have 5 records (even though we check for count of 3 records) and so on ....

Comment: The splitting of the file is done within the if block in the handler. This won't change. You need to find the right condition to trigger the split. I think if you add a counter that's incremented for each ROOT element, and reset when you split, the right condition will be the current one AND `$counter` > $MIN_ROOT_IN_FILE. You're already 80% of the way there, courage!

Comment: Thanks for the update mirod. the issue here is in the if loop I'm unable to reset the value after the max or min records value is reached... can u help in adding this condition along with the TAG1 value check ... thanks much ...

Comment: try some more. You have all the elements to do it.

Comment: Hi mirod ... badly need your help ... I'm actually very new to Perl and have very little knowledge .. I have included a $counter which increments for each ROOT and included the condition $counter > min_record ..but the thing is its not checking for record condition first and then later the actual tag value check ...please help me in including the condition which actually checks for the min_record check and then later check for TAG1 value and splits accordingly...

Comment: my output XML should be ..if the TAG1 value is ABC for first 2 records and DEF for the next 6 records ...and XYZ for last records ..and if min records in a file is 5 records ... the file should be split into 2 files (2 records for ABC & 6 records for DEF) and rest XYZ in second file ...

Comment: the condition is ` $nb_root_in_file > $MIN_ROOT_IN_FILE && $root->field( 'TAG1') ne $current_tag1` where `$nb_root_in_file` is declared before the `XML::Twig->new` instruction and incremented prior to the test, for each `ROOT` and `$MIN_ROOT_IN_FILE` would be 5 in your case. If the test is satisfied, then reset the counter.

Comment: I added the conditions as mentioned by you ... but still its not splitting based on count and TAG1 value ...not sure where its going wrong ..

Answer (score 2):

Atlast i found the fix ..
below is the code which will check for both the count and TAG values ....

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie qw( open);

use XML::Twig;

my $in_file = $ARGV[0];

my $out_file= "$in_file.p";
my $i="01";
my $current_tag1='';
my $previous_tag1 = '';
my $nb_root_in_file  =0;
my $MIN_ROOT_IN_FILE = 5;


my $twig=XML::Twig->new(   
twig_handlers => { 
   ROOT => sub { my( $t, $root)= @_;
   $current_tag1||= $root->field( 'TAG1');      # initialize current tag if needed
   $nb_root_in_file++;
   if( $nb_root_in_file > $MIN_ROOT_IN_FILE && $root->field( 'TAG1') ne $current_tag1)  # found a break in the value of TAG1 
                   { 
                     $root->cut;                   # get the new root out of the way
                     $t->print_to_file( $out_file. $i++);     # output the part
                     $t->purge;                       # remove the content of the part
              $root->paste( first_child => $t->root);  # put the new root back in place
                     $current_tag1=  $root->field( 'TAG1'); 
                     $nb_root_in_file =0;
                   }
                    $previous_tag1 = $current_tag1;
               }
 },
keep_spaces => 1, # to keep line returns
 );

 $twig->parsefile($in_file);
  $twig->print_to_file( $out_file . $i); # output the last part
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can parse it with

```
use XML::Simple;

my $xml = XMLin($your_xml);
```

and then something like

```
if ($xml->{HEADER}->[0]->{ROOT}->{TAG1} == $xml->{HEADER}->[1]->{ROOT}->{TAG1}) { ... }
```

i actually dont know the outcoming xml struc

Comment: the output should be split into multiple xml's based on the TAG1 value ...since TAG1 value is ABC for first 6 records ..these 6 records should be written into a new XML file name with extension as Part1 or so ... and since TAG1 value is different for the next 8 records ..these 8 records should be wrtitten to xml file name part2 and so on ....